# How to show multiple place route according to best Route in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to show a route between multiple lat long on android.I can show route between two point.But I want to show multiple points route according to best route path in google map.Like this site  [Click here](http://findthebestroute.com/RouteFinder.html). I am using android native programming .

Thank in advance..

Comment: Were you able to sole the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Directions API and construct your directions request with waypoints. From the API docs *"Waypoints allow you to calculate routes through additional locations."*

See - 
[Using Waypoints in Routes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Waypoints)