# Android: Draw direction in google map java

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps, location

how to find the best route for multiple locations in google maps api in android? I have some locations as LatLng but I dont know how specify a optimal route

Comment: Refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398697/how-to-show-multiple-place-route-according-to-best-route-in-google-map-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = latLongList;
            PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(8).color(
                    Color.RED);

            for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
            }

            // Adding route on the map
            map.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

> Try this , pass your list of latlongs in latLongList

Comment: hi my friend, I use the  above code but crashed my program , could you create simple google map project and set  five latlongs  ?   thank you

Comment: can you post the logcat because i cant find any possible reasons for crash

Comment: I upload my simple app , please look at it and advice me

Answer (score 1):

Using Google maps direction api you can acheive it, follow the documentation about using waypoints - 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints

Now a fully functional api looks like this -

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Here **origin** = starting point, **destination** = Ending point, **waypoints** = points that you want to cover, **optimize**:true = the route through the given waypoints will be optimized(i.e following Traveling Salesman Problem) and key = your map api key.

Now in order to save the api response here is the model class -

```
public class DirectionApiResponse {
private ArrayList<Geocoded_waypoints> geocoded_waypoints;

private String status;

private ArrayList<Routes> routes;

public ArrayList<Geocoded_waypoints> getGeocoded_waypoints ()
{
    return geocoded_waypoints;
}

public void setGeocoded_waypoints (ArrayList<Geocoded_waypoints> geocoded_waypoints)
{
    this.geocoded_waypoints = geocoded_waypoints;
}

public String getStatus ()
{
    return status;
}

public void setStatus (String status)
{
    this.status = status;
}

public ArrayList<Routes> getRoutes ()
{
    return routes;
}

public void setRoutes (ArrayList<Routes> routes)
{
    this.routes = routes;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [geocoded_waypoints = "+geocoded_waypoints+", status = "+status+", routes = "+routes+"]";
}


public class Geocoded_waypoints
{
    private String place_id;

    private String geocoder_status;

    private ArrayList<String> types;

    public String getPlace_id ()
    {
        return place_id;
    }

    public void setPlace_id (String place_id)
    {
        this.place_id = place_id;
    }

    public String getGeocoder_status ()
    {
        return geocoder_status;
    }

    public void setGeocoder_status (String geocoder_status)
    {
        this.geocoder_status = geocoder_status;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTypes ()
    {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes (ArrayList<String> types)
    {
        this.types = types;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [place_id = "+place_id+", geocoder_status = "+geocoder_status+", types = "+types+"]";
    }
}
public class Routes {
    private String summary;

    private Bounds bounds;

    private String copyrights;

    private ArrayList<String> waypoint_order;

    private ArrayList<Legs> legs;

    private ArrayList<String> warnings;

    private Overview_polyline overview_polyline;

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public Bounds getBounds() {
        return bounds;
    }

    public void setBounds(Bounds bounds) {
        this.bounds = bounds;
    }

    public String getCopyrights() {
        return copyrights;
    }

    public void setCopyrights(String copyrights) {
        this.copyrights = copyrights;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWaypoint_order() {
        return waypoint_order;
    }

    public void setWaypoint_order(ArrayList<String> waypoint_order) {
        this.waypoint_order = waypoint_order;
    }

    public ArrayList<Legs> getLegs() {
        return legs;
    }

    public void setLegs(ArrayList<Legs> legs) {
        this.legs = legs;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWarnings() {
        return warnings;
    }

    public void setWarnings(ArrayList<String> warnings) {
        this.warnings = warnings;
    }

    public Overview_polyline getOverview_polyline() {
        return overview_polyline;
    }

    public void setOverview_polyline(Overview_polyline overview_polyline) {
        this.overview_polyline = overview_polyline;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [summary = " + summary + ", bounds = " + bounds + ", copyrights = " + copyrights + ", waypoint_order = " + waypoint_order + ", legs = " + legs + ", warnings = " + warnings + ", overview_polyline = " + overview_polyline + "]";
    }

    public class Bounds
    {
        private Southwest southwest;

        private Northeast northeast;

        public Southwest getSouthwest ()
        {
            return southwest;
        }

        public void setSouthwest (Southwest southwest)
        {
            this.southwest = southwest;
        }

        public Northeast getNortheast ()
        {
            return northeast;
        }

        public void setNortheast (Northeast northeast)
        {
            this.northeast = northeast;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "ClassPojo [southwest = "+southwest+", northeast = "+northeast+"]";
        }

        public class Southwest
        {
            private String lng;

            private String lat;

            public String getLng ()
            {
                return lng;
            }

            public void setLng (String lng)
            {
                this.lng = lng;
            }

            public String getLat ()
            {
                return lat;
            }

            public void setLat (String lat)
            {
                this.lat = lat;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "ClassPojo [lng = "+lng+", lat = "+lat+"]";
            }
        }

        public class Northeast
        {
            private String lng;

            private String lat;

            public String getLng ()
            {
                return lng;
            }

            public void setLng (String lng)
            {
                this.lng = lng;
            }

            public String getLat ()
            {
                return lat;
            }

            public void setLat (String lat)
            {
                this.lat = lat;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "ClassPojo [lng = "+lng+", lat = "+lat+"]";
            }
        }
    }

    public class Overview_polyline {
        private String points;

        public String getPoints() {
            return points;
        }

        public void setPoints(String points) {
            this.points = points;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [points = " + points + "]";
        }

    }

    public class Legs {
        private Duration duration;

        private Distance distance;

        private End_location end_location;

        private String start_address;

        private String end_address;

        private Start_location start_location;

        private ArrayList<String> traffic_speed_entry;

        private ArrayList<String> via_waypoint;

        private ArrayList<Steps> steps;

        public Duration getDuration() {
            return duration;
        }

        public void setDuration(Duration duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
        }

        public Distance getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        public void setDistance(Distance distance) {
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        public End_location getEnd_location() {
            return end_location;
        }

        public void setEnd_location(End_location end_location) {
            this.end_location = end_location;
        }

        public String getStart_address() {
            return start_address;
        }

        public void setStart_address(String start_address) {
            this.start_address = start_address;
        }

        public String getEnd_address() {
            return end_address;
        }

        public void setEnd_address(String end_address) {
            this.end_address = end_address;
        }

        public Start_location getStart_location() {
            return start_location;
        }

        public void setStart_location(Start_location start_location) {
            this.start_location = start_location;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getTraffic_speed_entry() {
            return traffic_speed_entry;
        }

        public void setTraffic_speed_entry(ArrayList<String> traffic_speed_entry) {
            this.traffic_speed_entry = traffic_speed_entry;
        }

        public ArrayList<String> getVia_waypoint() {
            return via_waypoint;
        }

        public void setVia_waypoint(ArrayList<String> via_waypoint) {
            this.via_waypoint = via_waypoint;
        }

        public ArrayList<Steps> getSteps() {
            return steps;
        }

        public void setSteps(ArrayList<Steps> steps) {
            this.steps = steps;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ClassPojo [duration = " + duration + ", distance = " + distance + ", end_location = " + end_location + ", start_address = " + start_address + ", end_address = " + end_address + ", start_location = " + start_location + ", traffic_speed_entry = " + traffic_speed_entry + ", via_waypoint = " + via_waypoint + ", steps = " + steps + "]";
        }


        public class Duration {
            private String text;

            private String value;

            public String getText() {
                return text;
            }

            public void setText(String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "ClassPojo [text = " + text + ", value = " + value + "]";
            }
        }
        public class Start_location
        {
            private String lng;

            private String lat;

            public String getLng ()
            {
                return lng;
            }

            public void setLng (String lng)
            {
                this.lng = lng;
            }

            public String getLat ()
            {
                return lat;
            }

            public void setLat (String lat)
            {
                this.lat = lat;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "ClassPojo [lng = "+lng+", lat = "+lat+"]";
            }
        }

        public class End_location {
            private String lng;

            private String lat;

            public String getLng() {
                return lng;
            }

            public void setLng(String lng) {
                this.lng = lng;
            }

            public String getLat() {
                return lat;
            }

            public void setLat(String lat) {
                this.lat = lat;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "ClassPojo [lng = " + lng + ", lat = " + lat + "]";
            }
        }

        public class Distance {
            private String text;

            private String value;

            public String getText() {
                return text;
            }

            public void setText(String text) {
                this.text = text;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "ClassPojo [text = " + text + ", value = " + value + "]";

            }
        }

        public class Steps
        {
            private String html_instructions;

            private Duration duration;

            private Distance distance;

            private End_location end_location;

            private Polyline polyline;

            private Start_location start_location;

            private String travel_mode;

            public String getHtml_instructions ()
            {
                return html_instructions;
            }

            public void setHtml_instructions (String html_instructions)
            {
                this.html_instructions = html_instructions;
            }

            public Duration getDuration ()
            {
                return duration;
            }

            public void setDuration (Duration duration)
            {
                this.duration = duration;
            }

            public Distance getDistance ()
            {
                return distance;
            }

            public void setDistance (Distance distance)
            {
                this.distance = distance;
            }

            public End_location getEnd_location ()
            {
                return end_location;
            }

            public void setEnd_location (End_location end_location)
            {
                this.end_location = end_location;
            }

            public Polyline getPolyline ()
            {
                return polyline;
            }

            public void setPolyline (Polyline polyline)
            {
                this.polyline = polyline;
            }

            public Start_location getStart_location ()
            {
                return start_location;
            }

            public void setStart_location (Start_location start_location)
            {
                this.start_location = start_location;
            }

            public String getTravel_mode ()
            {
                return travel_mode;
            }

            public void setTravel_mode (String travel_mode)
            {
                this.travel_mode = travel_mode;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString()
            {
                return "ClassPojo [html_instructions = "+html_instructions+", duration = "+duration+", distance = "+distance+", end_location = "+end_location+", polyline = "+polyline+", start_location = "+start_location+", travel_mode = "+travel_mode+"]";
            }


            public class Polyline
            {
                private String points;

                public String getPoints ()
                {
                    return points;
                }

                public void setPoints (String points)
                {
                    this.points = points;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString()
                {
                    return "ClassPojo [points = "+points+"]";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now to draw the route in between way-points you can use the below method -

```
private void setRoutePath(DirectionApiResponse directionObj){
    gMap.clear();
    addMarkers(localLeedsArrayList);
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
    DirectionApiResponse.Routes route = directionObj.getRoutes().get(0);
    // Traversing through all the routes
    for(DirectionApiResponse.Routes.Legs leg : route.getLegs()){
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        Log.e("Route", leg.getStart_address()+" "+leg.getEnd_address());

        // Fetching all the points in i-th route
        //for(DirectionApiResponse.Routes.Legs.Steps step : leg.getSteps()){
        for(int j=0;j<leg.getSteps().size();j++){
            DirectionApiResponse.Routes.Legs.Steps step = leg.getSteps().get(j);
            points.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(step.getPolyline().getPoints()));
        }

        // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
        lineOptions.addAll(points);
        lineOptions.width(20);
        lineOptions.color(colors[count]);
        Polyline polylineFinal = gMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        count++;
    }
    Log.e("SouthWest",directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getSouthwest().getLat()+"  "+directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getSouthwest().getLng());
    Log.e("northeast",directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getNortheast().getLat()+"  "+directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getNortheast().getLng());

    /*LatLng lSouth = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getSouthwest().getLat()),
            Double.valueOf(directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getSouthwest().getLng()));
    LatLng lNorth = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getNortheast().getLat()),
            Double.valueOf(directionObj.getRoutes().get(0).getBounds().getNortheast().getLng()));
    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds(lNorth,lSouth);
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds,14));*/

    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()),15));
}
```

Here **gMap** is the google map object..

******* UPDATE Api Calling********

In order to call the api Create interface **IApiMethods** and put the code below -

```
@GET("json?origin=35.693391,51.424261&destination=35.692032,51.432715&waypoints=35.691997,51.432758")
Call<DirectionApiResponse> getDirectionWalking(@Query("key")String key);
```

you can change the co-ordinates accordingly

Now call the method below to call the api and get the DirectionApiResponse object

```
 private void getDirection(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    IApiMethods service = retrofit.create(IApiMethods.class);
    Call<DirectionApiResponse> directionApiResponseCall = service.getDirectionWalking("YOUR API KEY");
    directionApiResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<DirectionApiResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DirectionApiResponse> call, Response<DirectionApiResponse> response) {
            setRoutePath(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DirectionApiResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Finally add the following dependencies to the app's build.gradle file -

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
```

Comment: thank you but I have qutions, localLeedsArrayList refer to what? how can I assigne it ?

Comment: hi , could you send me above codes + main+ resource in  runable project copletely ? I cant used fom yout codes, thnks : ho.alimoradi#gmail .com

Comment: Actually this code is from an ongoing project, just follow the following steps and you can use it -

1. Create an Activity and call the api "https://maps.googleapis.com........" and get the json response.

2. Convert json response string into DirectionApiResponse object using Gson.

3. Call the method setRoutePath(DirectionApiResponse obj from step 2)

Let me know if you are facing any problem

Comment: how can I convert json response string into DirectionApiResponse object using Gson? please send the code , thanks

Comment: use this - new Gson().fromJson("json string",DirectionApiResponse.class);

Comment: hi myfreind, I faced this erorrs:"  GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin" and " com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1"

Comment: I think 1st error is because the map is not properly set-up -
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro

The 2nd error is because the api u calling returning string instead of json object

Comment: this is a example of the my key : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.693391,51.424261&destination=35.692032,51.432715&waypoints=35.691997,51.432758&key=AIzaSyB2cyH7mXydKt07kdjDswy7nyv4QWBs-VQ correcr in browser but in android has a error

Comment: I use this :Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();   DirectionApiResponse directionApiResponse = gson.fromJson(createUrl(), DirectionApiResponse.class);  setRoutePath(directionApiResponse);

Comment: In case of calling api use Retrofit, u dont have to use Gson manually. The api response is perfect, I tried and successfully created the route (its tehran). Now check the api calling section

Answer (score 0):

1. **How to get the route**

You might want to look at the Distance Matrix service: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

It gives you distances between a set of origins and destinations, and might help you with narrowing down options.

**2. To Find the best route :**

If using the web service, ensure you set optimize:true before listing your waypoints, and check the waypoint_order array.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adelaide,SA&destination=Adelaide,SA&waypoints=optimize:true|Barossa+Valley,SA|Clare,SA|Connawarra,SA|McLaren+Vale,SA&sensor=false

If use the JS API, set optimizeWaypoints:true in your request.

**3. To draw polyline with the latlongs you have**

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);

for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {

    LatLng point = list.get(z);
    options.add(point);

}

line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```